# How to add a fixed offset when using scrollTop()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to set a `position:fixed` to a div when it scrolls past the top of the screen. I have done this successfully with the following code:

```
   var $window = $(window),
       $stickyEl = $('#the-sticky-div'),
       elTop = $stickyEl.offset().top;

   $window.scroll(function() {
        $stickyEl.toggleClass('sticky', $window.scrollTop() > elTop);
    });
```

Where the CSS is:

```
     #the-sticky-div.sticky {
     position: fixed;
     top: 0px;
     width:100%;
     z-index:2000;
  }
```

My question: I want to modify this so that the div is held under a navbar of height 60px, rather than at the top of the page. I know I need to modify the CSS to `top:60px', but how do I add the 60px offset to the jquery so it sticks earlier rather than scrolling under the navbar first?

Thanks

Comment: Try `elTop = $stickyEl.offset().top + 60;`

Comment: @IanBrindley That should be an answer bro. Reap your sweet karma.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work; still scrolls under the navbar

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out:

```
  $window.scroll(function() {
        $stickyEl.toggleClass('sticky', $window.scrollTop() + 60 > elTop);
    });
```